How set ivec4 by Vertex Attributes?
I tried using an int value ‘flag’ to set different colors，but the 'flag' value is not correct.
l want know why failed to set value 'flag'??
the full demo project https://github.com/whiskets/OpenTKDemo.git
this is C# code
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 32)]
struct TestVertex
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public Vector3 Vertieces;
    [FieldOffset(16)]
    public int[] Id;
}

public class Window : GameWindow
{
   
    private int _vertexBufferObject;
    private int _vertexArrayObject;
    private Shader _shader;

   float[] floorVertices = new[]
   {
        -0.5f,   0.5f,  -0.0f,
         0.5f,    0.5f, -0.0f,
        -0.5f,  -0.5f, -0.0f,

        0.5f,    0.5f,  -0.0f,
        0.5f,   -0.5f,-0.0f,
        -0.5f,   -0.5f, -0.0f,
    };

    TestVertex[] _vertices = new TestVertex[6];
    public Window(GameWindowSettings gameWindowSettings, NativeWindowSettings nativeWindowSettings)
        : base(gameWindowSettings, nativeWindowSettings)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnLoad()
    {
        base.OnLoad();

        GL.ClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);

        for(int i =0;i< floorVertices.Length;i+=3)
{
    TestVertex a =new TestVertex();
    a.Vertieces = new Vector3(floorVertices[i], floorVertices[i + 1], floorVertices[i + 2]);
    var id = i / 9 + 1;
    a.Id = new[] { id, id + 1, id + 2, id + 3 };            
    _vertices[i/3] = a;
}
        _shader = new Shader("Shaders/shader.vert", "Shaders/shader.frag");
        _shader.Use();
        _vertexBufferObject = GL.GenBuffer();    
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, _vertexBufferObject);
        unsafe
        {
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, _vertices.Length * sizeof(TestVertex), _vertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
            _vertexArrayObject = GL.GenVertexArray();
            GL.BindVertexArray(_vertexArrayObject);
GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, sizeof(TestVertex), 0);
            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(1);
GL.VertexAttribIPointer(1, 4, VertexAttribIntegerType.Int, sizeof(TestVertex), 16);
          
        }
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    }

    protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnRenderFrame(e);
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);
        _shader.Use();
        GL.BindVertexArray(_vertexArrayObject);
        GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, 6);
        SwapBuffers();
    }

vert shader
#version 430 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 aPosition;
layout(location = 1) in int flag;

out vec3 Color;

void main(void)
{   
     if(flag[0]==0)
          Color=vec3(1.0,0.0,0.0);
     else if(flag[0]==1)
          Color=vec3(0.0,1.0,0.0);
     else if(flag[0]==2)
          Color=vec3(0.0,0.0,1.0);
     else 
          Color=vec3(1.0);
    gl_Position = vec4(aPosition, 1.0);
}

frag shader
#version 430

in vec3 Color;
out vec4 outputColor;

void main()
{
    outputColor = vec4(Color,1.0);
}

the code in C++ is right,l think maybe the porblem is C# int[] is different C++.but l dont know why
l tried change struct size,or VertexAttribPointer offset but it also not work
